# usar argparse con archivo json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, parser, argparse

tengo un mi proyecto en python y mi intención es usar argparse para que según el parametro que yo le pase por la terminal me traiga datos especificos desde un archivo json. He creado algunos argumentos con argparse pero no logro hacerlos funcionar correctamente. tengo este archivo json:

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "name": "ac",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "20%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "63%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acv",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "37%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acf",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "48%"
    },
    {
      "name": "ach",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "error",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "10%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acj",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "23%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acq",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "65%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "20%"
    },
        {
      "name": "bcc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "25%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcx",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "error",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "4%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcn",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "50%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcm",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "35%"
    }
  ]
}
```

entonces lo que yo quiero hacer es por ejemplor ejecutando mi programa desde la terminal y usando el paramentro -s services por ejemplo es traer solamente los servicios desde el json file o si pongo -d diskusage traers solo el uso de los discos.
tengo estos parametros hasta ahora creados y hice estas def pero al ejecutar el programa me trae tanto servicios como discos

```
import json
import argparse
import logging


#open json data
with open('services.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    def add_argument(data):
        print('Services:')
    for service in data['services']:
        print(service['name'])

def print_service_disk_usages(data):
    print('Disk Usage:')
    for service in data['services']:
        print(f'{service["name"]}:\t{service["disk usage"]}')

#argparse parameters config
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f",
                    "--fullreport",
                    help="printing the full report",
                    default="*")
parser.add_argument("-g",
                    "--graphreport",
                    help="printing the graph report",
                    default="*")
parser.add_argument("-s",
                    "--services",
                    help="services to be test",
                    default=add_argument(data))
parser.add_argument("-d",
                    "--diskusage",
                    help="see the disk usage",
                    default=print_service_disk_usages(data))

args = parser.parse_args()
```

la verdad es que soy bastante nuevo en esto de scriptear en python pero agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: No responde a tu pregunta, pero si necesitas hacer herramientas de línea de comandos que admitan muchas opciones y no te quieres complicar la vida, echa un vistazo a `click`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que estaría bien es definir en una función que te devuelva el json, para así guardarlo en una variable. No se cómo está estructurado tu script ni nada, por eso te doy una solución. He modificado algo los métodos (intenta no llamar a una función igual qué un método de un paquete, módulo...), por eso he cambiado el nombre de la función add_argument. He modificado el parser para que recojas después el argumento según su opción y hacer el código que necesites.

```
def get_data():
    with open('services.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return data

data = get_data()

def add_data(p):
    print('Services:')

    for service in p['services']:
        print(service['name'])

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f",
                    "--fullreport",
                    help="printing the full report")
parser.add_argument("-g",
                    "--graphreport",
                    help="printing the graph report")
parser.add_argument("-s",
                    "--services",
                    help="services to be test")
parser.add_argument("-d",
                    "--diskusage",
                    help="see the disk usage")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.fullreport:
    print("Añadir funcionalidad")
elif args.graphreport:
    print("Añadir funcionalidad")
elif args.services:
    add_data(data)
elif args.diskusage:
    print_service_disk_usages(data)
```

Si ejecutas

```
python nombre_script.py -s diskusage
```

Te saldrá por pantalla el porcentaje del disco.

NOTA. No he comprobado errores de tipos a la hora de meter agumentos ni nada y no está todo el código, solo lo que he modificado. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Predro! muchisimas gracias esto me ha funcionado de maravilla, tengo una consulta mas.... digamos que por ejemplo quiero en la terminar ejecutar mi app con 2 argumentos -s para los servicos y -d para disk usage puedo usar ambos argumentos en el mismo proceso es decir puedo ejecutar lo siguiente : 
test.py -s services -d diskusage
lo he probado pero solo me da el ultimo parametro es decir si pongo ultimo los discos me trae solo los discos y si pongo servicios solo los servicios.
alguna idea?
Agradezco mucho tu ayuda.

Comment: Hola, si puedes hacerlo. Lo único modifica la parte de los if y no metas un else if o elif. Prueba a hacerlo así:
if args.services:
    add_data(data)
if args.diskusage:
    print_service_disk_usages(data)

A parte, si quieres añade en el add_argument el type para que recoja como argumento un string. Que quede así: 
parser.add_argument("-d",
                    "--diskusage", type=str,
                    help="see the disk usage")
Espero esto también te ayude

Comment: Pedro te hago una consulta que me surgio tratando de hacer mas funcional o dinamico el codigo.... supongamos que yo quiero ver un servicio en especifico y no simplemente que me imprima todos, es eso posible? como por ejemplo que ponga en la terminar -s ac u otro servicio o disco a chequear. Gracias.

Comment: Hola @MaximilianoCorrea, Lo que quieres ahora es pasar por parámetro el nombre de un servicio y que te muestre únicamente ese servicio no?? Si es así piensa que en el if recoges el valor que pones. Por lo que en args.services tienes el parámetro que pones. Para hacer lo que quieres puedes hacer comprobaciones adicionales como podrían ser: if args.services: (Compruebas que existe un arg -s, pero su valor es ac), dentro de ese if tendrías que comprobar cada uno de los valores o hacer un método que según sea el valor te saque uno u otro valor. Tendrías que modificar tu código para que lo imprima